# Cannot access Nexus Repository Manager 3 with the REST API

Tags: rest, nexus, sonatype

I written a lot of scripts for a Nexus Repository Maanager with the version 2.11, where i use the [REST API](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html) to uploading and downloading several components.

Now, it was upgraded to the version 3.1 and neither scripts work well. I always get the response code 404 Not Found.

I found in the [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-plugins.html), that the plugin Nexus Core API should be installed, but i cannot found any plugins on the Nexus Repository Manager 3

How can i use all of the scripts with the version 3.1? Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you reference is for the Nexus 2.x documentation. Nexus Repository Manager 3.x does not currently have a REST API, however it is on the roadmap. At current time you could look at using the Provisioning/Scripting API to accomplish what you intend to do.

Comment: I like Nexus but having no REST API seems like a step backward.  Is there a date or version that you've planned to include them?

Comment: REST API is next on our list. Expect our first movement in version 3.3

Comment: So Nexus 3.3 is out now. No RESTful API in the release notes there. Any thoughts Darth?

Comment: I've altered the deal @DaveBrunkow , pray I don't alter it any further (just kidding, it's very close).

Comment: how to access the nexus rest api using post method